# Still loads previous version after upgrading latest version OpenCV 4.4.0

Tags: opencv, pip

I upgraded **OpenCV 4.4.0** from OpenCV 4.2.x with pip command :

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-python==4.4.0.40
```

and checked the upgrade completed :

```
Collecting opencv-python==4.4.0.40
     |████████████████████████████████| 33.5 MB 283 kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\users\kangs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python==4.4.0.40) (1.18.5)
    Found existing installation: opencv-python 4.3.0.36
      Successfully uninstalled opencv-python-4.3.0.36
PS C:\Users\kangs\Documents\TELPA\Source\numberplateRecognition> python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 17:30:36) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.4.0'
>>> exit()
```

However, I still get this error message when I run this code :

```
cv2.dnn.readNet(WEIGHTS, CFG)
```

Error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kangs\Documents\TELPA\Source\numberplateRecognition\number_plate_v4c.py", line 54, in <module>
  File "c:\Users\kangs\Documents\TELPA\Source\numberplateRecognition\algorithm\detection\yolodetector.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.load_dir(dir_path)
  File "c:\Users\kangs\Documents\TELPA\Source\numberplateRecognition\algorithm\detection\yolodetector.py", line 50, in load_dir
    self.load_files(file_list)
  File "c:\Users\kangs\Documents\TELPA\Source\numberplateRecognition\algorithm\detection\yolodetector.py", line 78, in load_files
    self.net = cv2.dnn.readNet(WEIGHTS, CFG)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp:686: error: (-212:Parsing error) Unsupported activation: mish in function 'cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'
```

I found out that the code still linked to the previous library **OpenCV 4.2.0**.
Can someone please let me know why this happens and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Since you have specifically upgraded it to `4.4.0` instead of letting pip install the latest one, the 4.4.0 module is installed in a different package. Remove that specific one and just use the latest one from opencv-python which will overwriter the previous and then you can use the latest one. The latest one as for now is `4.4.0.42`. Use the `pip install --upgrade opencv-python`

Comment: @JimitVaghela According to your advice, I just let pip install latest version : `pip install opencv-python` after uninstall previous version : `pip uninstall opencv-python` , but I still have the same problem. Do you know how to delete the specific one?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? `pip uninstall opencv-python` should uninstall each version that you have in the site-packages. After that just use, `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: @SeunggyKang when you use `pip install opencv-python`, it installs the latest version. Have you tried `pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: @JimitVaghela I figured that my site-packages path is here : `C:\Users\kangs\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`. But, the error link from previous opencv (4.2.0) is here : `C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp:686`.

Comment: @JimitVaghela I found out where the problem causes. I use VSCode. In my code, OpenCV version is still **4.2.0**, but I upgraded it in _python debug console_, and it is **4.4.0**.

Comment: That explains the question that I asked about the virtual environment. If you are using an IDE like VsCode or PyCharm, it is better to install the library packages in the virtual environment itself using the IDE's VE console. Just like your `Python Debug Console`

Comment: I solved it. I was not aware of different virtual environment. I changed to a current virtual env in VSCode to the latest one, and every upgrades are now applied. Thank you.